# How to generate/validate JWT token with JwtSecurityTokenHandler and Compression DEFLATE in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, compression, jwt

In Java, I see that, it have option

```
JwtBuilder b = Jwts.builder()
.compressWith(CompressionCodecs.DEFLATE);
```

But in .net core, I don't know how to generate a JWT token which compress with the `DEFLATE`, similar to java. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can create and apply own compression providers. For example, to use **Deflate** compression:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace CompressionApp
{
    public class DeflateCompressionProvider : ICompressionProvider
    {
        public string EncodingName => "deflate";
        public bool SupportsFlush => true;

        public Stream CreateStream(Stream outputStream)
        {
            return new DeflateStream(outputStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
        }
    }
}
```

The `EncodingName` property specifies the compression format that the client supports. This format is contained in the `Accept-Encoding` header in the request to the server, like:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
```

That is, this provider will work if the client sent the value of `deflate` in the request in the `Accept-Encoding` header.

The `SupportsFlush` property specifies whether the record is reset to a stream.

The `CreateStream ()` method returns the response stream itself after compression or actually wrapping over the initial response thread that is passed as a parameter to the method. For compression, the built-in class DeflateStream() is used.

Apply this provider in the `ConfigureServices()` method of the `Startup` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
    {
        options.Providers.Add(new DeflateCompressionProvider());
    });
}
```

To add a provider, the `options.Providers.Add()` method is called.